# Python 3: My for loop is replacing my last list entry instead of appending to it

Tags: list, python-3.x, csv, for-loop

I have two problems but I think resolving one issue will resolve the other.
My aim is to move to several different webpages and find the line that contains the node name, I have managed to create a for loop for this which is working fine. the only issue every time my for loop runs again its removing the last node name entry from the list and adding the new one in its place, thus only leaving one node name in the list.

THE FULL CODE RELATING TO ISSUE

```
    webstringy = "mycompanysite.com/?NodeID="
webpage = "mycompanysite.com/?NetworkID=36"
r2 = s2.get(webpage)
bsobjswap = BeautifulSoup(r2.content)
gotopagenums = [re.findall("\d+", i.get('onclick')) for i in bsobjswap.findAll('tr', attrs={'onclick':True})]
#link = (len(gotopagenums))
print (gotopagenums)
results = open("niki2.csv", 'w', newline='')
wr2 = csv.writer(results, dialect='excel')
for i in gotopagenums:
    wr2.writerows([i])
for nodeno in gotopagenums:
    nodenojoin = "".join(nodeno)
    weblink = [webstringy+nodenojoin]
    for weblnky in weblink:
        r2 = s2.get(weblnky)
        bsobjswap2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content)

    nodename = [(bsobjswap2.h1.span)]
    test = [nodename]
    test3 = '\n'.join(str(e) for e in test)
    #if test3.startswith("[<span"):
       # if test3.endswith("</span>]"):
    test4 = (test3[72:])
    test5 = (test4[:-9])
    test5 = [test5]
    print (test5)


    resultfile = open("niki.csv", 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(resultfile, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
    for i in test5:
        wr.writerows([i])
        wr.writerows('\n')
```

Now, when I run this the first csv file (niki2.csv) works fine and i am assuming this is because all entries are in one list (each list entry is added to csv in separate row as I want)

PROBLEM CODE

```
        for weblnky in weblink:
        r2 = s2.get(weblnky)
        bsobjswap2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content)

    nodename = [(bsobjswap2.h1.span)]
    test = [nodename]
    test3 = '\n'.join(str(e) for e in test)
    #if test3.startswith("[<span"):
       # if test3.endswith("</span>]"):
    test4 = (test3[72:])
    test5 = (test4[:-9])
    test5 = [test5]
    print (test5)


    resultfile = open("niki.csv", 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(resultfile, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
    for i in test5:
        wr.writerows([i])
        wr.writerows('\n')
```

this is the part of code my issue is, I believe. when I print the test5 list during the for loop i get

FOR LOOP OUTPUT

```
['GG Alperton']
['GG Angel']
['GG Ashford']
['GG Barking']
['GG Bedford']
['GG Birmingham']
['GG Bolton']
['GG Bothwell Street']
['GG Bournemouth']
['GG Bracknell']
['GG Brighton London road']
['GG Brighton Madeira']
['GG Bristol']
['GG Cardiff']
['GG Chadwell Heath']
['GG Charing Cross']
['GG Chelmsford']
['GG Colchester']
['GG Crawley']
['GG Croydon']
['GG Dartford']
['GG Derby']
['GG Ealing']
['GG East Croydon']
['GG Eastbourne']
```

and when I print test5 outside the loop i get

```
['GG Eastbourne']
```

which is of the last entry so when I try and write out to a csv it only contains this entry.

I need to please please please know how to get all the entries above into one list so I can print them properly to a .csv.

I've tried appending, mapping, joins, more and more for-loops I cannot figure it out.

OUTPUT FROM GAURAV DHAMA

```
 [['GG Alperton']]
 [['GG Angel']]
 [['GG Ashford']]
 [['GG Barking']]
 [['GG Bedford']]
 [['GG Birmingham']]
 [['GG Bolton']]
 [['GG Bothwell Street']]
 [['GG Bournemouth']]
 [['GG Bracknell']]
 [['GG Brighton London road']]
 [['GG Brighton Madeira']]
 [['GG Bristol']]
 [['GG Cardiff']]
 [['GG Chadwell Heath']]
 [['GG Charing Cross']]
 [['GG Chelmsford']]
 [['GG Colchester']]
 [['GG Crawley']]
 [['GG Croydon']]
 [['GG Dartford']]
 [['GG Derby']]
 [['GG Ealing']]
 [['GG East Croydon']]
 [['GG Eastbourne']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change code to :

```
mylist = []
for nodeno in gotopagenums:
    nodenojoin = "".join(nodeno)
    weblink = webstringy+nodenojoin
    r2 = s2.get(weblink)
    bsobjswap2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content)
    nodename = [(bsobjswap2.h1.span)]
    test = [nodename]
    test3 = '\n'.join(str(e) for e in test)
    #if test3.startswith("[<span"):
    # if test3.endswith("</span>]"):
    test4 = (test3[72:])
    test5 = (test4[:-9])
    test5 = [test5]
    mylist.append(test5)

print mylist
resultfile = open("niki.csv", 'w')
wr = csv.writer(resultfile, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
for i in mylist:
    wr.writerow(i)
```

Why are you creating unnecessary lists in your code, you do not need the internal loop.

Comment: thanks for the response but I am still getting the same output with only the last entry being in the list

Comment: ive added how the output looks now to the bottom of my question

Comment: I have edited the answer, please check your results once again

Comment: sadly not now the only result i get back is [['GG Eastbourne']]

Comment: It will work now, you were creating a lot of unnecessary lists in your code

Comment: sorry about the unnecassary i get abit carried away while testing but relating to the new code i get

Comment: File "rb3.py", line 75, in findingdata
    test4 = test3[72:]

Comment: return self.attrs[key]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: Lets retake some of your earlier code then. Problem is I do not know the content that you are pulling from that webpage, so it becomes kind of a blackbox for me. But it is an issue of improper indentation of for loops and not saving iterating variables. Check the one posted now.

Comment: thankyou pal that worked perfectly really appreciate you helping me

Comment: Happy to help mate!!